# Given coordinates of points find distance between diagonals of parallelepiped.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given parallelepiped $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$ find distance between $AC_1$ and $BD$.

$A = (-1,2,-3)$, $B = (1,4,1)$, $D= (3,2,-7)$, $A_1= (-7,0,0)$

So what I am doing is I tried to find coordinate of $C$ then to find coordinate of $C_1$.So in order to find coordinate of $C_1$ we need to equal length of $CC_1$ to $AA_1$ but I can't do anything after this.
Maybe I am on the wrong way and there is much easier solution?Any help

Answer (score 1):

In a parallelepiped, there is a special relation:

$$
\vec{C}_{1}=\vec{B}+\vec{D}+\vec{A}_{1}-2\vec{A}
$$

After you find $\vec{C}_{1}$, next we need to find the minimum distance.

To do this, find a vector that is orthogonal to both $\vec{C}_{1}-\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}-\vec{D}$ (hint: cross product). Normalize this vector. Finally, find the dot product of this normalized vector to  $\vec{B}-\vec{A}$.

Comment: Thanks for response.Can you share some resources that proof what you said?

Comment: @HrantBaloyan try this one http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.04/aman1.html

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a parallelipiped, you can use relationship between equal sides: use $C-B=D-A$ to get $C$. Then use $C_1-C=A_1-A$.
So $$C-(1,4,1)=(3,2,-7)-(-1,2,-3)$$
$$C=(5,4,-3)$$
I hope you can continue from here.